# How to sum up Values of a column grouped by another column of the same table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm new in Power BI and have some questions. Actually, I have a table like the following:

| id | weight |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |

So, I had to join many tables to obtain all the necessary data, but I encounter issues when attempting to retrieve the weight for a single id.
I wish to have the total sum of weight = (20 + 2) = 22 using a DAX formula or any other method in Power BI, perhaps in the Power Query Editor.

I actually tried a DAX formula, and the result works, but all my facts have to be in a fact table since I don't want to create additional tables other than the fact table and the dimensions I already have.
Simply said, I wish to have a star schema with all facts in the fact table and descriptions in the dimensions.

```
Table = 
GROUPBY(
    FactsAmounts,
    id,
    weight,
    "Max weight",
    MAXX(CURRENTGROUP(), weight)
)
```

I would be glad if someone could help :).

Greetings.